# Exercise from "Moduli of Curves"

Tags: algebraic-geometry, deformation-theory

I am struggling with Exercise 1.5 from the book "Moduli of Curves" by Harris and Morrison. Namely, I want to show that $\mathbb{P}^1_{\mathbb{C}}$ is a fine moduli space of lines through the origin in $\mathbb{C}^2$.

**Edit:**

I want to phrase the question differently and more detailed. Here are my thoughts. First of all, by $\mathbb{C}^2$ I mean the affine space $\textrm{Spec} (\mathbb{C}[x,y])$. And a line through the origin is a subscheme corresponding to an ideal generated by $\lambda x+\mu y$ where $\lambda, \mu \in \mathbb{C}$ are not both zero. Now consider the functor $F$ from the category of schemes over $\mathbb{C}$ to the category of sets that sends a scheme $X$ to the set of subschemes $W \subseteq \mathbb{C}^2 \times X$ (together with the projection on $X$) that have the property that the fiber over every $\mathbb{C}$-point of $X$ is a line through the origin (the fiber is embedded to $\mathbb{C}^2$ via the projection). I want to show that $F$ is isomorphic to $\textrm{Mor}_{\mathbb{C}}(-,\mathbb{P}^1_{\mathbb{C}})$. So I want to find two natural transformations $F\to \textrm{Mor}_{\mathbb{C}}(-,\mathbb{P}^1_{\mathbb{C}})$ and $\textrm{Mor}_{\mathbb{C}}(-,\mathbb{P}^1_{\mathbb{C}})\to F$ that are inverse to each other. For the second one there is a natural candidate coming from the tautological bundle over $\mathbb{P}^1_{\mathbb{C}}$. But my problem is to show that this has an inverse: So I have a subscheme $W \subseteq \mathbb{C}^2 \times X$ that has the property that the fiber over every $\mathbb{C}$-point of $X$ is a line through the origin and I have to find a corresponding morphism $X \to \mathbb{P}^1_{\mathbb{C}}$. This means that I have to associate a line bundle to $W$ that is generated by two global sections. I guess to do that, one takes sections of the projection map $W \to X$. This gives a sheaf on $X$, but why is it coherent and locally free of rank one?

Comment: What is your definition of fine moduli space here?

Comment: I think $M$ is a fine moduli space if the functor $\textrm{Mor}_{\mathbb{C}}(-,M)$ is isomorphic to the functor that associates to a scheme $X$ over $\mathbb{C}$ the set of all $W \subseteq \mathbb{C}^2 \times X$ such that the fibers over $\mathbb{C}$-points of the projection $W \to X$ are lines through the origin in $\mathbb{C}$. I think the book is not too precise here (e.g. I don't know if the families should be flat).

Comment: I'm not sure what `lines through the origin' means. I feel like you'd have to choose an embedding. I'm sure you know what the usual functor $\mathbb{P}^1_\mathbb{C}$ represents (surjections $\mathcal{O}^2\to \mathscr{L}$). How do you think that translates into this line through the origin business. I mean, $\mathbb{P}^1_\mathbb{C}$ is the quotient $[\mathbb{A}^2_\mathbb{C}-\{0\}/\mathbf{G}_m]$ which qualifies it as lines through the origin, but somehow I don't feel like that should make you happy :P

Comment: Hi Alex, thaks for your comments. I have rephrased the question so that now it is perhaps clearer to you (and other people) what my problems is.